# UICollectionView doesn't scroll inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm having an issue with UICollectionView scrolling inside UITableViewCell.

Unfortunately, the CollectionView doesn't scroll at all. When I'm trying to disable other UITableViewCells it works without any problem and vice versa.

**CollectionViewCell:**

```
import UIKit

class CategoriesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init(coder adecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(codeer:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var categoriesImage: UIImageView = {
        let categoriesImage = UIImageView()
        categoriesImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        categoriesImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        categoriesImage.image = UIImage(named: "pizza")
        categoriesImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        categoriesImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        categoriesImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoriesImage
    }()

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .black
        containerView.alpha = 0.7
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var categoryName: UILabel = {
        let categoryName = UILabel()
        categoryName.textColor = .white
        categoryName.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        categoryName.text = "Soup"
        categoryName.textAlignment = .left
        categoryName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoryName
    }()

    lazy var recipesNumber: UILabel = {
        let recipesNumber = UILabel()
        recipesNumber.textColor = .white
        recipesNumber.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 16)
        recipesNumber.text = "33"
        recipesNumber.textAlignment = .left
        recipesNumber.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return recipesNumber
    }()

    func setupcategoriesImageConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoriesImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            categoriesImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            categoriesImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            categoriesImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesImage.topAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesImage.bottomAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesImage.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesImage.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCategoryNameConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoryName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            categoryName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            categoryName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16)
        ])
    }

    func setuprecipesNumberConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            recipesNumber.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            recipesNumber.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            recipesNumber.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16)
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(categoriesImage)
        categoriesImage.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(categoryName)
        containerView.addSubview(recipesNumber)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupcategoriesImageConstraints()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupCategoryNameConstraints()
        setuprecipesNumberConstraints()
    }
}
```

**CollectionViewInTableViewCell:**

```
import UIKit

class CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let categories = ["italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food"]

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var categoriesNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let categoriesNameLabel = UILabel()
        categoriesNameLabel.text = "Categories"
        categoriesNameLabel.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        categoriesNameLabel.textAlignment = .left
        categoriesNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        categoriesNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoriesNameLabel
    }()

    lazy var seeAllCategoriesButton: UIButton = {
        let seeAllCategoriesButton = UIButton()
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitle("See all", for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitleColor(.CustomGreen(), for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        seeAllCategoriesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
        return seeAllCategoriesButton
    }()

    @objc func test() {
        print("Test worked")
    }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CategoriesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell")
        return collectionView
    }()

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesNameLabel.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoriesNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            categoriesNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            seeAllCategoriesButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            seeAllCategoriesButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCollectionViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesNameLabel.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(categoriesNameLabel)
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(seeAllCategoriesButton)
        containerView.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupCollectionViewConstraints()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints()
        setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints()
    }

}

extension CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 2, height: self.frame.width / 4)
    }

}
```

**TableViewCell:**

```
import UIKit

class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        containerView.layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 2, height: 2)
        containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 7.0
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
//        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var foodImage: UIImageView = {
        let foodImage = UIImageView()
        foodImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        foodImage.clipsToBounds = true
        foodImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        return foodImage
    }()

    lazy var foodTitle: UILabel = {
        let foodTitle = UILabel()
        foodTitle.textColor = .CustomGreen()
        foodTitle.numberOfLines = 0
        foodTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return foodTitle
    }()

    func setupContainerView() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }

    func setupFoodImage() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            foodImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            foodImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            foodImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250)
        ])
    }

    func setupFoodTitle() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foodImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            foodTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            foodTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            foodTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(foodImage)
        containerView.addSubview(foodTitle)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubview()
        setupContainerView()
        setupFoodImage()
        setupFoodTitle()
    }

}
```

**HomeView:**

```
class HomeView: UIView {

    var recipes: Recipes?
    var recipesDetails = [Recipe]()
    let indicator = ActivityIndicator()

    override init( frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var foodTableView: UITableView = {
        let foodTableView = UITableView()
        foodTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodTableView.backgroundColor = .white
        foodTableView.delegate = self
        foodTableView.dataSource = self
        foodTableView.register(CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell")
        foodTableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell")
        foodTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
//        foodTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        foodTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        foodTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return foodTableView
    }()

    func setupFoodTableView() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            foodTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            foodTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            foodTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(foodTableView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        indicator.setupIndicatorView(self, containerColor: .customDarkGray(), indicatorColor: .white)
        addSubview()
        setupFoodTableView()
        fetchData()

    }

    func fetchData() {
        AF.request("https://api.url").responseJSON { (response) in
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
            }
            do {
                self.recipes = try JSONDecoder().decode(Recipes.self, from: response.data!)
                self.recipesDetails = self.recipes?.recipes ?? []
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.foodTableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            self.indicator.hideIndicatorView()
        }
    }

}

extension HomeView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return recipesDetails.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        let url = URL(string: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].image ?? "Error")
        cell.foodImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
        cell.foodTitle.text = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return 160

        } else {
            return 250
        }

    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem or what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If anyone has this problem in the future, for me it was simply *not* having `User Action Enabled` check marked for the inside collection view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot scroll your collection view because it is outside the bounds of its superview. In your code, you have this line:

```
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesNameLabel.heightAnchor)
```

That makes your `containerView` height ***only*** around 20-pts, but you also have your collection view as a subview of `containerView`.

Here is how your code looks for me (pretty much as-is):

[image]

And, I cannot scroll the collection view.

You can confirm it is outside the `containerView` bounds by giving `containerView` a background color (I used cyan):

[image]

You can also confirm it by setting `containerView.clipsToBounds = true`:

[image]

Now, we don't even ***see*** the collection view.

You have a couple other constraint issues, but they don't really relate to being unable to scroll the collection view.

Your layout is also a *little* confusing, in that you have your `Categories` label *outside* your `containerView`... it seems it would make much more sense to have that label + the "See All" button + the collection view ***all*** inside the `containerView`.

I made a few edits to your `CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell` which resolves that issue -- and I *think* is close to your ultimate goal. You may need to do a little tweaking, but hopefully it will give you a good direction.

```
class CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let categories = ["italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food"]

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var categoriesNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let categoriesNameLabel = UILabel()
        categoriesNameLabel.text = "Categories"
        categoriesNameLabel.textColor = .gray // .customDarkGray()
        categoriesNameLabel.textAlignment = .left
        categoriesNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        categoriesNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoriesNameLabel
    }()

    lazy var seeAllCategoriesButton: UIButton = {
        let seeAllCategoriesButton = UIButton()
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitle("See all", for: .normal)
//      seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitleColor(.CustomGreen(), for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        seeAllCategoriesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
        return seeAllCategoriesButton
    }()

    @objc func test() {
        print("Test worked")
    }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CategoriesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell")
        return collectionView
    }()

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            // should not be constrained to categoriesNameLabel height
            //containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesNameLabel.heightAnchor)
            // constrain 16-pts from bottom of cell
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
    }

    func setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoriesNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            // centerY to seeAllCategoriesButton
            categoriesNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seeAllCategoriesButton.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            seeAllCategoriesButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            // constrain top to containerView top
            seeAllCategoriesButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCollectionViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seeAllCategoriesButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        // but categoriesNameLabel inside containerView
        //addSubview(categoriesNameLabel)
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(categoriesNameLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(seeAllCategoriesButton)
        containerView.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupCollectionViewConstraints()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints()
        setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints()
    }

}
```

The result looks like this - and you can see that I have scrolled the collection view a bit:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
Can you help me with another issue? it's the height for UITableViewCell, it's broken and I can't see the error for what I made.

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz - I posted a full set of classes here: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/e70610ab127adcc426f90a91a26d4149 ... see if that gives you the layout you want.

Comment: Thanks its Working for me my Problem was that I am adding Collection View Directly in Cell but now I first add container view then add CollectionView in Container view and Its working Like a Charm

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and I found that just because the structure of tableViewCell.

cell - cell's contentView

**Wrong way**

addSubview(aView)

cell - aView - cell's contentView

you can't interact with aView

**Correct**

self.contentView.addSubview(aView)

cell - cell's contentView - aView

Now you can interact with aView.

Just change the line

addSubview(containerView)

to

self.contentView.addSubview(containerView)

will fixed your problem.